# How to properly close QWebView without result in memory leak?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, memory-leaks, qwebview

I have a custom `QWebView` declared as:

```
class browserControl : public QWebView {
  Q_OBJECT
 public:
         explicit browserControl(QWidget *parent = 0);
         ~browserControl();
  // ....
}
```

it's a member of `MainWindow` class (the same one generated by Qt on GUI applications) I call [show()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#show) when a button is hit. So it open the web browser in a new windows but when I close either the main window our the web browser it I got a bunch of memory leaks (it may differ from each run, depending on what the page opened, I guess) like (if I close main windows then browser)

> LEAK: 24 CachedResource
>
> LEAK: 231 WebCoreNode

Or if I close the browser then main window:

> LEAK: 1 XMLHttpRequest
>
> LEAK: 49 CachedResource
>
> LEAK: 2528 WebCoreNode

How do I fix this?

**EDIT**

The constructor code as asked:

```
browserControl::browserControl(QWidget *parent)
    : QWebView(parent)
{
}

browserControl::~browserControl()
{
}
```

Comment: Can you post constructor code? And how you construct this object?

Comment: @MehrdadMomeny: Check out the edit. I put the consturctor code. The object is a member of main window class (the one generated by Qt in a GUI application). I didn't set a parent. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: If you didn't set a parent and didn't delete the widget manually, how do you expect it to be deleted?

Comment: @MehrdadMomeny: When I set the parent to main windows the browser gets embeded in the main window's form on top of a tab control in the same form. Which parent should I use or how do I delete it manually?

Comment: Check the second option in my answer, with that you don't need to set the parent.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. You can pass a parent QObject, which is directly or indirectly a child of your QApplication object, to constructor of the widget. Since destructor of qobject delete its children, eventually your widget will be deleted.
2. Second option is that you set `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute on your widget, this way it will be deleted when you close the widget itself, and won't be waiting for the application to be closed. do this: `widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);`